# Converting .py to .exe with pandas imported for all users not having pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyinstaller

I'm new to Python, but I have set up an python script for searching some specific Values in 2 different excel sheets printing out matches (in excel).

Problem is, that our work machines are heavily locked down and without admin privileges, we can't really install anything (we can download though). Is there any version of Python that is Windows 7 compatible that will run standalone without requiring any sort of installer? 
I have tried pyInstaller, but the problem is that in my script we need PANDAS. 
And there is no possibility to pip install pandas to our local machines. All  is blocked. ("pip install pandas" is not possible. I did the code with Anaconda)

So my question is: how can I set up a file for my coworkers, who have no permission to download pandas?

Can I set up an exe file (all use windows 7/10) in my private computer where pandas is already installed and forward it to the workers?

It should be very easy for them to use--> double click for executing the python script

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use pyinstaller which personally I find the easiest to use. It can bundle executables for both Linux and Windows, but it must be run on that architecture that you wish to have executable for, i.e. if you want to have Linux executable the pyinstaller command with your code must be run on Linux OS of some kind.

More here: https://www.pyinstaller.org/

Answer (score 0):

This is old so you may already have found a solution but this might help others.

Python by default is an **interpreted** language. This means that compiling it into an `.exe` file is impossible.
However, using some modules it is indeed possible to convert a `.py` script into a windows executable.
You can try [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org).

> py2exe is a Python Distutils extension which converts Python scripts
>   into executable Windows programs, able to run without requiring a
>   Python installation.

They have a tutorial [here](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial).